Is there a set of documents that contain only the necessary definitions needed to implement UEFI?
I have been reading through the UEFI 2.6 specification, and have noticed that it does not give a complete list of definitions need to implement UEFI. Rather, the definitions are scattered across sections of the document, making it very tedious for anyone who wants to implement UEFI to implement it. It would appear the specification writers have a reason for not supplying the interface in a developer friendly manner.

Stackoverflow is for questions, not commentary or conspiracy theories. Ultimately your "question" contains no question. Please rewrite.

The question is in the title. If not, just say no.

No there is not such a document(s),

why not make this yourself? others have done this for their own projects

@J.Doe I already use EDK2. There really is no reason for me to make one when there are existing ones. I noticed that GNU has their own EFI library that is described as not mature. The Linux kernel also has created an EFI library for it's own EFI stub.
I find the Linux kernel EFI API to be quite disappointing compared to EDK2s, but perhaps they have their reasons for it.
